# PHP OAuth Signature Mismatch

Tags: php, oauth

I am trying to learn and play around with PHP's implementation of OAuth as defined [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.oauth.php). I am not using a library of some sort, just the pure OAuth implementation, as I am trying to learn it. However, as basic as I am trying to make it, I can not seem to get the signatures to match.

On the consumer side I have:

```
<?php
$consumer_key = '1234';
$consumer_secret = '1234';
$url = 'http://localhost/oauth/provider/request';

try {
    $oauth = new OAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
    $signature = $oauth->generateSignature('POST', $url);
    $request_token = $oauth->getRequestToken($url);
    var_dump($signature);
    print_r($request_token);
} catch (OAuthException $E) {
    var_dump($E);
}
```

On the provider side I have:

```
<?php

function call(){
    return OAUTH_OK;
}

$OAuthProvider = NULL;

try{
    $OAuthProvider = new OAuthProvider();
    $OAuthProvider->consumerHandler('call');
    $OAuthProvider->timestampNonceHandler('call');
    $OAuthProvider->tokenHandler('call');
    $OAuthProvider->isRequestTokenEndpoint(true);
    $OAuthProvider->checkOAuthRequest();
}
catch(Exception $ex){
    echo $OAuthProvider->signature;
}
```

Pretty simple right? Then the error message from the caught exception I get is "Signatures_do_not_match". I have checked, and indeed, the signatures do not match. Here is an example of the output:

```
Consumer: 8cePFQFqJbL3hY6OjZe6kw63irc=
Provider: 2SPGA0GcC7GLLR1Jte53xz_bWOY
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, I did not read the spec on the callback functions properly. The implementation that works is:

Consumer:

```
<?php

$consumer_key = '1234';
$consumer_secret = '1234';
$url = 'http://localhost/oauth/provider/request';

try {
    $oauth = new OAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
    $signature = $oauth->generateSignature('POST', $url);
    $request_token = $oauth->getRequestToken($url);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    var_dump($ex);
}
```

And the provider:

```
<?php
$OAuthProvider = NULL;

function consumerHandler(){
    return OAUTH_OK;
}

function timestampNonceHandler(){
    global $OAuthProvider;
    /**
     * Here is supposed to be a function to check if 
     * the consumer secret is legit, and is then used to check if the signatures match.
     */
    $OAuthProvider->consumer_secret = '1234';
    return OAUTH_OK;
}

try{
    $OAuthProvider = new OAuthProvider();
    $OAuthProvider->consumerHandler('consumerHandler');
    $OAuthProvider->timestampNonceHandler('timestampNonceHandler');
    $OAuthProvider->isRequestTokenEndpoint(true);
    $OAuthProvider->checkOAuthRequest();
}
catch(Exception $ex){
    var_dump($ex);
}
```

Hope this helps someone that wants to learn about OAuth like I did.